# How to differentiate between Values in String Array in c#

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, substring

I have a string array which contains value like this ..

```
1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **
```

Now sometimes my string array contains value like this..

```
SNo Date Time Number Duration/Volume Amount
```

Here is my code which is splitting string called **line** into string array **split**

```
string[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
```

Now my question is what condition i can write to segregate between these two string array values ?

Comment: what you  mean by segregate between the two values written the start of the post??

Comment: First define what uniquely identifies the two types of values.

Comment: @K.B i have to deal 1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 ** this differently and SNo Date Time Number Duration/Volume Amount differently when both of these are present in the same string array called split

Comment: If you are sure that those lines will start with number, you can just check that in a `where` filter.

Comment: @mathew yes sir i want to check only those lines in split array of string which starts with number but dont know how to do it .Please elaborate

Comment: split[0].Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c)) checks first string if it contains any digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> _dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string line = "1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **";
string line1 = "SNo Date Time Number Duration/Volume Amount";
line.Replace('*', ' ');
string[] split1 = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
string[] split2 = line1.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

for (int _i = 0; _i < line.Length; _i++)
{
    _dic.Add(split1[_i], split2[_i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you only concerned with getting the data values,

i.e. `1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40` ?

If the data is consistently formatted this way, I'd probably approach it with a regular expression, and everything that gets matched, continue with your

`string[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });`

so you know you'll not have any of your header data involved.

**Edit**: this should work for you.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


Regex rgx = new Regex("\d+\s+\d{1,2}/(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)/[12]\d{3}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+.\d+\s+\*\*");
if (rgx.IsMatch(line))
{
    string[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
    //process your data, etc
}
```

Comment: yes sir i want only these values 1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 ** and omit characters value .Thats why i am asking what condition i can write to diffrentiate between two?

Answer (score 0):

> 1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **

In your case the first item (S.No) is integer. By using this we can get the valid lines from the string array like follows.

```
var lines = new[] { "1 03/MAR/2013 06:41:06 9448485859 00:15 0.40 **",
                    "SNo Date Time Number Duration/Volume Amount" };
int serialNumber;
IEnumerable<string> validLines = lines.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && 
                                  int.TryParse(s.Split(' ')[0], out serialNumber));
```

In the above example, I just checked for the serial number. If you need a perfect result, you can check for Date, Phone Number, Duration, Amount in the above Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
string[] split = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Where(x =>char.IsDigit(x[0])).ToArray();
```

This assumes that you only want those lines which starts with a digit.